# While Running postman collection through Newman how to clear cache/Cookies during each iteration

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

While running collection for n iteration - I get desired result during first iteration but for all subsequent iteration as session cookies are stored I don't get desired Response as it is cookies are stored

Comment: It looks like this is being worked on and will be addressed here:
https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman/issues/429

Answer (score 1):

To clear cookies you have to write a script to delete the cookies for the domain you are accessing. Something like this:

```
const jar = pm.cookies.jar();
jar.clear(pm.request.url, function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

but first you have to whitelist your cookies before trying to delete them. To whitelist cookies, click on the "**Cookies**" tab under Postman request page, then click on Whitelist and add your domain.